# Dynamically load dashboard content in angular2

Tags: angularjs, angular, material-design

I have an angular2 application with the following meterial design layout

[image]

I have separated the sidebar, header and dashboard into separate components. I want to load the dashboard in the middle dynamically based on the user cliks on the sidebar.

how can this be achieved. any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router, RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,CanActivate} from 'angular2/router';
import {AuthHttp,AuthConfig, tokenNotExpired, AUTH_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2-jwt';


import {HomeComponent} from '../home/HomeComponent'
import {AboutComponent} from '../about/AboutComponent'
import {HeaderComponent} from './HeaderComponent'
import {LoginComponent} from '../login/LoginComponent'
import {AuthService} from '../../services/AuthService'
import {SidebarComponent} from './SidebarComponent'
import {DashboardComponent} from './DashboardComponent'


@RouteConfig([
    {path: 'app/home', component: HomeComponent, as: 'Home'},
    {path: 'app/about', component: AboutComponent, as: 'About'},    
    {path: 'app/login', component: LoginComponent, as: 'Login'},
    {path: 'app/*', redirectTo: ['Login']}   // this redirect is not working for some reason
])
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
   template: `
    <body>
    <div class="demo-layout mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-drawer mdl-layout--fixed-header">
      <app-header class="demo-header mdl-layout__header mdl-color--grey-100 mdl-color-text--grey-600"></app-header>
      <app-sidebar class="demo-drawer mdl-layout__drawer mdl-color--blue-grey-900 mdl-color-text--blue-grey-50">
      </app-sidebar>
      <main class="mdl-layout__content mdl-color--grey-100">
        <dashboard></dashboard>
      </main>

    <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>
  </body>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `, 
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,SidebarComponent,HeaderComponent,DashboardComponent],
    providers: [AUTH_PROVIDERS,AuthService]
})

export class AppComponent { 

  constructor() {}

}
```

Comment: Why do you have your `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` outside of your `body` element? This tag is used to set the place for rendering the output of your routes (Home, About, Login ...)

Comment: Shouldn't make any difference as long as it's inside the template `` .. as far as i understand it.

Comment: No, `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` is a placeholder which gets replace with the actual content of your components you get routed to. I think what you want is to replace your `dashboard` tags with the `router-outlet`.

Comment: it kinda worked .. but the dashboard template is displayed at the very bottom of the page and not in the right panel as intended. any ideas ?

Comment: Sorry my bad .. I didn't remove the other router outlet from the bottom that's why. It's working now. if you could answer this, I'll mark it as accepted. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RouterOutlet is a place holder for the content of your components you get routed to. It should be placed where you expect the content of the route to be rendered. In your case simply replace the `dasboard` tags with the `router-outlet` tag you placed at the bottom of the template like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
   template: `
    <body>
    <div class="demo-layout mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-drawer mdl-layout--fixed-header">
      <app-header class="demo-header mdl-layout__header mdl-color--grey-100 mdl-color-text--grey-600"></app-header>
      <app-sidebar class="demo-drawer mdl-layout__drawer mdl-color--blue-grey-900 mdl-color-text--blue-grey-50">
      </app-sidebar>
      <main class="mdl-layout__content mdl-color--grey-100">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </main>

    <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>
  </body>
    `, 
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,SidebarComponent,HeaderComponent],
    providers: [AUTH_PROVIDERS,AuthService]
})
```